# Зависание программы .net при вызове system()

Tags: c++, .net, winforms

Столкнулся с проблемой. В Visual Studio создал GUI на WinForm .net. Написал код, и тут вылезла проблема. При вызове приложения(в моем случае zoom) с аргументами(или без них) через `system()`, gui запускается, приложения открывается, командная строка не закрывается(даже если второй командой поставить exit), а вот мое приложение(gui и т.д) просто зависает, отвисает оно только тогда когда закроется командную строку(или zoom закроет командную строку). В моем случае такой поведение недопустимо.
Знаю что это можно исправить вызывая приложение через process встроенный в WinForm но у меня в аргументах используется %APPDATA%, %USERDATA% и т.д(они используются в изменяемом конфига так что просто поставить APPDATA который подерживает process я не могу) которые не распознает process.

Кусок кода вызова приложения:

```
system((zoom_dir + " --url=" + (string)ini[day()]["link7"].c_str()).c_str());

zoom_dir =  %appdata%\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил всьо таки вместо system() использовать process.start().
Проблему с %appdata% решил с помощью replace.